# CSS Content with a Font Awesome light icon

Tags: css, font-awesome

I have the following CSS code

```
content: "\f061";
color: #006697;
font-family: FontAwesome;
```

to add a right arrow after an element, but I'd like the arrow to be light not bold. Font-weight property doesn't work and I can NOT add HTMT like "i class="fal fa-arrow-right" in the content attribute.

Anyone knows how I can achieve this? Thanks

**Edit**:
I found this method to reduce the weight of the stroke
    -webkit-text-stroke: 2px #3EC5E6;
But my issue is I m using a background with opacity and I have some issue with to match the colors because of the alpha

**Edit2**
I switched to an RGB color instead of RGBA and the above solution works great now

Comment: what font-awesome version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably use the classes `fas` and `fa-arrow-right`. Instead of `fas` use `fal`. But that's only for Font Awesome 5 Pro.

**Edit:**

Use `font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Light"`, which is also available for Font Awesome 5 Pro.

Comment: I can't put any html in the content attribute, I can only use the unicode "\f061"

Comment: @RezaSaadati Thank you. I am not willing to subscribe to the pro version yet, but I found a solution with -webkit-text-stroke: 2px. Upvoting your response

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if something in FA5 Pro has changed in a recent version, but the accepted answer from Reza Saadati didn't work for me - I had to do this:

```
p:before{
    font-family:"Font Awesome 5 Pro";
    font-weight:300;
    content:"\f10d";
}
```